# GET/POST запрос в JSON (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, json

Не могу сообразить...
Вот получаю строку, разбиваю её по амперсандам.

```
var form = ($('.form').serialize()).split('&');
```

Нужно преобразовать в JSON, для передачи по ajax, чтобы в php после json_decode можно было получить массив key => value

Comment: зачем, если есть http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Слишком долго объяснять. Делается интеграция в 1с, на сайте отправляются данные скрипту в виде json. Нужно воссоздать аналог js скрипта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = JSON.stringify($( "form" ).serializeArray());
```

отправка:

```
$.ajax( {
  type: "POST",
  url: 'myHandler.php',
  data: {json: data},     
  success: function( response ) {
    console.log( response );
  }
});
```

php файл

```
print_r(json_decode($_POST['json'], true));
```

Обрати внимание, что в данном случае надо использовать **[serializeArray](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B2_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2)**, который возвращает массив объектов, содержащий данные элементов формы, а не `serialize`. А потом, собственно, отправить json строку

---

**UPD:** Если не все получится как надо и нужно сделать json как `key=value`, где `key` - имя параметра в форме, а `value` - значение параметра в форме, то можно поступить так:

```
var result = { };
$.each($( "form" ).serializeArray(), function() {
    result[this.name] = this.value;
});
```

то есть сформировать  через цикл объект из полученного массива и потом его отправить:

```
$.ajax( {
  type: "POST",
  url: 'get.php',
  data: {json: JSON.stringify(result)},   
  success: function( response ) {
    console.log( response );
  }
});
```

---

**Дополнение:**

В случае если в форме присутствуют массивы данных, нужен более глубокий проход..Приложу сразу пример с html и js:

```js
// функция глубокого прохода и сериализации
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

// обработка
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // применение кастомного метода для сериализации и преобразование в json строку 
  var data = $('form').serializeObject();
  console.log(data);  
  data = JSON.stringify(data);

  // отправка
  
  $.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      url: 'myfile.php',
      data: {json: data},   
      success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
      }
    }); 
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>  
 <input type="text" name="firstname" value="122223"><br>  
 <input type="text" name="lastname" value="123">
  
 <input type="text" name="firstname22" value="122223"><br>  
 <input type="text" name="lastname33" value="123">
  
 <input type="text" name="firstnameasd" value="122223"><br>  
 <input type="text" name="lastnameasdasda" value="123">
  
 <input type="text" name="name[]" value="5" />
 <input type="text" name="email[]" value="555" />

 <input type="text" name="name[]" value="6" />
 <input type="text" name="email[]" value="666" />

 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Он же на https://jsfiddle.net/3mw6vzww/

Comment: Да, всё работает, спасибо большое. А избавиться от name/value есть возможность? Нужно подобие get - a=1&b=2... Где "а" ключ, а "1" значение

Comment: @azhirov1991 добавил в ответ. скорее всего нужно б даже вот так сделать объект `var result = { };
$.each($( "form" ).serializeArray(), function() {
    result[this.name] = this.value;
});` и затем отправить это как json строку

Comment: Ты гений чувак, спасибо тебе большое!) Я как раз на статью наткнулся)) http://javascript.ru/forum/jquery/56160-serializaciya-form-v-json.html